# Is Politics StackExchange Beta biased and promoting violence?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I have just published [this legitimate question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/61957) related to current political affairs in the US. I got immediately several downvotes, an admin deleting my comments while defending the legitimacy of my question and the question closed. All this happened in less than 10 minutes.

I ask for the reopening of my legitimate question closed only by ideological reasons.

Comment: Same procedure of harassment as before: just published and already a -1 vote with 0 answers and 0 comments!

Comment: @Fizz said wrongly that my question is not valid because you can ask the same question about many things that was going to be my answer before my question being definite deleted in case you can still see i as adminst: Additionally, that a question can be asked about many subjects does not invalidate these questions... Metaphysic and an important part of philosophy is basically about some abstract exact "really existing"... This does not invalidate philosophy. As mathematical analysis is not invalidate by the fact it answers basically to the kind of questions "is this greater than that?".

Comment: I saw that other users (https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4709/why-did-my-trumps-speech-question-get-the-response-that-it-did) have been experiencing a similar issue in this site. If not solved here, I will go to the main site as this behaviour and bias can eventually damage the reputation of all SE project.

Comment: FYI: downvotes on meta have a [somewhat different meaning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites). They can be used to express mere disagreement with the question/post.

Comment: I've removed the part about comments made by another user. While meta is the right place to ask why your question was closed and deleted, this is not the place to demand an apology from another user who may have said something in a now-deleted comment. If a comment is abusive, the right course of action is to flag it. It will then be reviewed by moderators who can take appropriate action.

Comment: For what it's worth, we downvote, close, and delete anti-Trump questions, too.  See [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61966/does-donald-trump-plan-to-flee-the-country) from a few hours ago.  Of course, since deleted questions aren't visible to most users it's hard to actually _see_ that both sides are affected the same; therefore with one data point, it's easy to see "bias".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your downvotes both here and there are more about your own misrepresentations or misinterpretations. You start off with a pretty aggressive tone and never stop to reflect on what others provide to you as feedback. I don't personally believe that points to the user-base here being biased, but rather the OP themselves.

I was not around to witness this question being closed/deleted, but would have supported it nonetheless. It is not a good fit in it's current form for a Q/A site looking to provide objective answers to questions asked in good faith.

My observations about the original question:

1- You misrepresent why Trump was banned from Twitter. He was not banned for that video.

2- As evidence for the previous, I can point you to [Twitter's own blog post](https://blog.twitter.com/en_us/topics/company/2020/suspension.html) on the matter.

3- I think, please correct me if I'm wrong, that the meat of your question is really why does there seem to be a double standard between the treatment of Trump by Twitter and that of other political figures who you believe have made comments similar to that of Trump and yet faced no such permanent suspension.

This last point I think is actually a pretty good question! However, you need to be able to ask in such a way which doesn't come off as so aggressive, and to be able to take and incorporate feedback from the community without feeling as though you are being personally attacked. There is a lot of times more than one way to interpret a speaker's (or writer's) message, and disclaiming bias while repeatedly performing the same is just a recipe for people to wind up tuning you out.

Comment: Ok your is actually a substantial and good answer even though you defend to restrict my speech. I have to say that your first point does in fact make sense and I maybe oversimplified in that in order to keep a short question (people complain when questions are too long also). Your second point is pointless because, by referring to the Twitter's blogpost, you are basing your arguments in a from-origin-biased information as it comes as a defence of the same site being under investigation via this question. I can only agree with your third point. However, let me point more in ur last paragraph...

Comment: ... I was not being aggressive at all but assertive with the level of attack and harassment that my question provoked towards me as the OP. As you can see I accept, discuss, and acknowledge respectful and constructive critic and feedback but what I received was not anything constructive but destructive towards me and my curiosity. I felt attacked because I was. I feel personally attacked only when this attack comes directly to my person, as happened. I pointed out that there was bias when a legitimate (as you recognise in point 3) question got attacked with a -5 just 1 minute after being psted

Comment: There was bias. My question was not aggressive. There is nothing aggressive in a question that point out strong, important, true and relevant information. But anyway, if someone thinks that the question could be improved I aim people to provide (positive, constructive) feedback: there is an option to edit question in order to add information that ones considers relevant. I didn’t get that but just an instant blockage to continue expressing myself and defending my question, the second block of this characteristic in a week. Pitiful, sad and lamentable for a site like SE that has such a good rep

Comment: I am beginning to think that either my English is too bad to be considered a person here (which would be xenophobic) or the site is plainly BIASED these days and trying to silence, ban and suppress and important part of the conversation about what is happening those last days of Trump's mandate. Anyway, thanks for your respectful answer (first one I receive in Politics SE Beta, it had to be in Meta...)

Comment: @Hvjurthuk As Fizz commented below, "bigotry, harassment, and abuse" and comments that "attack a person or group" are not allowed here. If you see someone doing that, flag the comment or post and a it will be deleted, either by a mod or an automated process, and the user will get disciplined if it's appropriate

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not. ([See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_lesson) how uninformative an answer to such a q can be?)

---

To copy my earlier comments here regarding the "Is Twitter biased" question, slightly edited for clarity:

What I was trying to convey in my comments on the question before we were... ahem... interrupted (by the question being deleted) is that a question that simply asks for a judgment like "is X biased" is a poor fit for this site. See also prior discussions on similar issues here: [Why did the question "Is President Donald Trump a racist?" get closed?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/why-did-the-question-is-president-donald-trump-a-racist-get-closed)

On the other hand, If you can think of a way to ask a question about bias that can be answered in some kind of objective fashion, such as e.g. the [relative voting patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideological_leanings_of_United_States_Supreme_Court_justices#/media/File:Graph_of_Bailey_Scores_of_Supreme_Court_Justices_1950-2011.png) of Supreme Justices--that is a reasonable way of asking an objective question about bias. I myself am not sure how to make such a question about Twitter that would be answerable with [systematic] public data though, i.e. not a mere anecdote.

Comment: What about the violence and harassment?

Comment: @Hvjurthuk: if you think some post or comment is doing either, flag it for moderator's attention.